# затык с выводом модального окна после ajax-запроса

Tags: ajax

```
function submitForm(){
var date_of_purchase   = $('#date_of_purchase').val();
var time_of_purchase   = $('#time_of_purchase').val();
// var bill_number   = $('#bill_number').val();
var unp_number = $('#unp').val();
var ean_first = $('#ean_first').val();
var ean_second = $('#ean_second').val();
var bill_number = $('#bill_number').val();
var file_data = $('#photo').prop('files')[0];
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('file', file_data);
form_data.append('date_of_purchase', date_of_purchase);
form_data.append('time_of_purchase', time_of_purchase);
// form_data.append('bill_number', bill_number);
form_data.append('unp_number', unp_number);
form_data.append('ean_first', ean_first);
form_data.append('ean_second', ean_second);
form_data.append('bill_number', bill_number);
$.ajax({
            url: 'add_payment.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,
            type: 'post',
            success: function(php_script_response){
            if(php_script_response=='no') //если такой чек уже зарегистрирован
                {


                $("#reg-done").modal({
                backdrop: 'false',
                keyboard: 'true'
                });
                }
            else
                { 

                // $('#register').modal('hide');
                $('.reset').val('');
                $('#fileupload').find('img:first').attr('src', 'img/upload2.png');
                $("#desc-code1").css("display", "none");
                $("#desc-code2").css("display", "none");
                $("#reg-check-sps").modal({
                backdrop: 'false',
                keyboard: 'true'
                });

                }

            }
});
```

}

Код собирает форму и отправляет в обработчик. Там проверка: если такая запись уже была зарегистрирована (ответ 'no'), то модальное окно (оно выводится). Если не была зарегистрирована, то соответственно проводится регистрация и должно выводиться окно об успешной регистрации. Так вот регистрация работает, а окно почему-то не выскакивает. В чем может быть проблема?
Самое интересное, что перенес с это все с тестового домена на рабочий. На тестовом все работало. 
В консоли браузера ошибок не показывает

Comment: `dataType: 'json'` и `'no'` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'add_payment.php',
            type: 'json', // вместо dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,
            method: 'post', // вместо type
            success: function(php_script_response) {
                    if (php_script_response == 'no') // здесь скорее всего тоже ошибка
                    {


                        $("#reg-done").modal({
                            backdrop: 'false',
                            keyboard: 'true'
                        });
                    }
```

Comment: тоже самое, запись добавляется, но модал не выводится

Answer (score 0):

нашел в чем проблема
почему то по первому клику возвращает error, а второй уже success